# ERROR: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

When I run the code below

```
$id = Input::get('branch_id');
$retailer_code = DB::table('branches')->select('retailer_code')->where('id', $id)->first();
$user = new User;
$user->user_firstname = Input::get('user_firstname');
$user->user_lastname = Input::get('user_lastname');
$user->user_email = Input::get('user_email');
$user->username = Input::get('username');
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
$user->position_id = Input::get('position_id');
$user->retailer_code = $retailer_code;
$user->branch = Input::get('branch_code');
$user->status = "1";
$user->save();

return Redirect::to('admin/users')->with('message', 'New User Added!');
```

I get this error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably on this line:

```
$user->retailer_code = $retailer_code;
```

`$retailer_code` is an object and you need to get the property of it like this:

```
$user->retailer_code = $retailer_code->retailer_code;
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. But how is it possible that you have to get the property like you said `$retailer_code->retailer_code;` when you are clearly specifying in the query that you want to get only the column `->select('retailer_code')`? That'd make sense if you only had `$retailer_code = DB::table('branches')->where('id', $id)->first();` (without the `->select('retailer_code')`)

Answer (score 3):

$retailer_code which is stdClass and you cannot use directly as variable ,

```
$retailer_code = DB::table('branches')->select('retailer_code')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

will returns the retailer_code so

```
$retailer_code->retailer_code //would be the solution.
```

Please refer this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
$user->retailer_code = $retailer_code;
```

into

```
$user->retailer_code = $retailer_code->retailer_code;
```

or you could modify your query:

```
$retailer_code = DB::table('branches')->where('id', $id)->pluck('retailer_code');
```

and then use:

```
$user->retailer_code = $retailer_code;
```

without a change