# Laravel 5.6 Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string when updating a database value

Tags: php, laravel-5

Kindly note this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053674/error-object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-string) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771351/laravel-object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-string)
I have a model page with json field called `options`.
in my page model, i have added the attribute options to the `$cast` variable and in the `$fillable` variable.
Then i have a function pageOptions() that's suppost to return a class PageOptions like so:

```
/*
 *@return pageOptions
 */
 public function pageOptions() : PageOption
{
   $options = ($this->options) ? ($this->options) : [];
    return new PageOption($options, $this);
}
```

the Page option class simply exposes functions of set() and get() to enable me set and get json data from the options field.
the set() method, simply sets data to a $options variable then calls the persist method that pushes data to the options field in the database.

```
 /**
     * Persist the options.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function persist()
    {
        return $this->model->update(['options' => $this->options]);
    }

Instead
```

i get this error

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

i am not trying to echo any object or array anywhere in my code so i cannot really understand where the error is coming from . . I have tried to `json_encode` the options variable manually in the persist() method but i still get the same error. I also tried adding the `TOString()` magic method on the pages and PageOptions classes like so

```
public function __toString()
     {
      return $this->name;
     }
```

but still does not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `$casts` property on the model.

```
protected $casts = [
    'options' => 'array'
];
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting):

> The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns
>   that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model.